# print part of a field with awk

Tags: awk

I run:

```
  ss -atp | grep -vi state | awk '{ print $2"   "$3"   "$4"  "$5"   "$6 }'
```

output:

```
0   0   192.168.1.14:49254  92.222.106.156:http   users:(("firefox-esr",pid=696,fd=95))
```

From the last column, I want to strip everything but `firefox-esr` (in this case); more precisely I want to only fetch what's between `""`.

I have tried:

```
ss -atp | grep -vi state | awk '{ sub(/users\:\(\("/,"",$6); print $2"    "$3"   "$4"   "$5"    "$6 }'
0    0   192.168.1.14:49254   92.222.106.156:http    firefox-esr",pid=696,fd=95))
```

There is still the last part to strip; the problem is that the `pid` and `fd` are not a constant value and keep changing.

Comment: `grep -vi state | awk '{do stuff}'` = `awk 'tolower($0) !~ /state/{do stuff}'`. If you show us the output of `ss -atp` that you need a script to parse then we can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might harness `gensub` reference ability for that. For simplicity let `file.txt` content be

```
users:(("firefox-esr",pid=696,fd=95))
```

then

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*"(.+)".*/,"\\1",1,$1)}' file.txt
```

outputs:

```
firefox-esr
```

Keep in mind that `gensub` do not alter string it gets as 4th argument, but return new string, so I `print` it.

Comment: @@Daweo: Could you please explain \\1,1,$1   ?

Comment: First argument is regular expression which will span whole width of column with so-called group enclosed in `( )` - in this case everything between `"` and `"`. `\\1` denotes content of first (and in this case only) group. `1` denotes first (and in this case only) match. `$1` denotes first column (for simplicity I used example with just one column). For more data about `gensub` function and examples see [GNU AWK String-manipulation Functions documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
awk '{ gsub(/^[^\"]*\"|\".*/, "", $6); print $2"   "$3"   "$4"  "$5"   "$6 }'
```

Here, `gsub(/^[^\"]*\"|\".*/, "", $6)` will take Field 6 as input, and remove all chars from start till the first `"` including it (see the `^[^\"]*\"` part) and then the next `"` and all text after it (using `\".*`).

See [this online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/GzprfM):

```sh
s='0 0   0   192.168.1.14:49254  92.222.106.156:http   users:(("firefox-esr",pid=696,fd=95))'
awk '{gsub(/^[^\"]*\"|\".*/, "",$6); print $2"   "$3"   "$4"  "$5"   "$6 }' <<< "$s"
# => 0   0   192.168.1.14:49254  92.222.106.156:http   firefox-esr
```